# CRM 2011 subgrid - custom form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Could you please help me with my issue.

I have custom entity (for example **custom_X**).
In Invoice(CRM) I created subgrid - this is view for **custom_X**.

In **custom_X** I have field *type*.

So my question: 
How can I open default form for **type 1** and custom form for **type 2**? 
(This is one entity. So it is posssible?)

[image]

Comment: I"m not entirely sure of what you're asking, but is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107663/how-to-set-a-default-form-from-sub-grid/16108511#16108511

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to make a custom grid using a 3rd party control set (i.e. KendoUI or ExtJS). If you want to use OOB functionality, I supposed you can have a form load event on the main custom entity form which will redirect to the form you want based on type.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted - upvoted to get you back to even. :)